# How to use longtabu like table* in twocolumn paper

Tags: tables, tabu, longtabu

I want to use longtabu in twocolumn paper in latex. My table has a lot fo rows and columns, so I want it to be full-width. I know longtabu does not support twocolumn and it throws error message when using it in twocolumn mode.
I manually switched to one column mode by \onecolumn command and returned to twocolumn mode by \twocolumn. But it makes new page with lots of blank spaces before and after by using these commands.
I want to do exactly what table* environment do. I mean without effecting other commands following longtabu.
How can I do this?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can try `\afterpage{\onecolumn longtable \twocolumn}` or `\afterpage{\afterpage{\onecolumn longtable \twocolumn}}` you can use `\if@firstcolumn`

Comment: @touhami Thank you for your answer. It works except that after table definition following  blank space remains. If I can remove page break(blank space) it will be what I want.

Comment: For me it works well text following the table fill the space and the table wait for next page. I use `longtable` package  i don't know for `longtabu`.